# How to assert page's header text

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I'm automating a webapp using TestNG, webdriver java.

I need to assert the header text in order to make sure if I'm navigating to the expected page. My page has no title so I can't use getTitle method, instead I tried to use the below code to assert the header's text.

My code:

```
String expectedUserClientPage = "Clients>TestCompany>Users"; 

    WebElement divElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/h2[2]"));
String str = divElement.getText();
Assert.assertEquals(str, expectedUserClientPage,"User Client page is not found!");
```

HTML code:

```
  <h2>
    <a href="http://abcd.com">
    <span style="margin:0px 10px;">›</span>
    <span style="font-size:9pt;">TestCompany</span>
    <span style="margin:0px 10px;">›</span>
    Users
  </h2>
```

Note: Here my main concern is to get the 'Users', but as Users is linked with Clients and TestCompany, I'm getting this error:

java.lang.AssertionError: User Client page is not found! expected [Clients>TestCompany>Users] but found [Clients?TestCompany?Users]

In my app, the header looks like this Clients > TestCompany > Users

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post what you get in the str variable

Comment: In str, I got [Clients?TestCompany?Users]

Comment: I think you can use replace function. I feel you are getting the right output but there is content mis match. Replace ">" with "?"

Comment: I just debug my code, in str I'm getting Clients›TestCompany›Users. I dont understand why the webdriver is showing Clients?TestCompany?Users as actual result. :(

Comment: I replaced > with ? but still same error

Comment: ahhh the ">" sign is creating problem..I debug my program and got str = Clients›TestCompany›Users. But when I paste this in expecteduserclientpage = 'Clients›TestCompany›Users' and save , it says "Cannot be save as Some characters can be save using US-ASCII, either change the encoding and remove characters that are not supported". Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hey guys, its working now. I did nothing, it saved it and now actual and expected r same (Y)